# How to create SET in Flow Salesforce?

Tags: visual-workflow

How I can achieve below code using flows:

```
AcctSeedERP__Outbound_Inventory_Movement__c[] tfrs = [
    SELECT Id,
        Warehouse_To__c,
        AcctSeedERP__Warehouse__c,
        AcctSeedERP__Product__c,
        Lot__c,
        Warehouse_To_and_Product_ID__c
    FROM AcctSeedERP__Outbound_Inventory_Movement__c
    WHERE Inventory_Transfer__r.Warehouse_To__r.Category__c = 'Consignment'
    AND Inventory_Transfer__r.Transfer_Shipped__c = False
    AND AcctSeedERP__Type__c = 'Transfer'];

Set<String> myIds = new Set<String>();                                                      
for (AcctSeedERP__Outbound_Inventory_Movement__c  tfr : tfrs) {
    myIds.add(tfr.Warehouse_To_and_Product_ID__c); 
}    

List<Par_Level__c> parLevelsNeedingStock = [
    SELECT ID
    FROM  Par_Level__c 
    WHERE Unique_Id_For_Warehouse_Product__c NOT IN : myIds
    AND Difference_From_Par__c < 0
    AND Warehouse_Category__c = 'Consignment'];
```

And How Can I use "parLevelsNeedingStock " List in next for loop.  I tried but i am getting confused where to close first for loop and how to start next for loop.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can create the list of ids/Objects as a variable resource in the flow.

In the Flow Builder -> Toolbox -> Manager -> click 'New Resource' button.
Which will open a dialog like below:

[image]

From there:

- Select Resource Type as Variable
- Choose the API name
- Select Data Type as Text in case of Id.(SObjects and other datatype are supported too).
- Check the box = Allow multiple values (collection)
- Check the Availability checkbox as required.

You can use the same variable in the loop logic.
[Flow Documentation](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=flow_builder.htm&type=5)

Comment: Hey Rahul Thanks.